# Least square approximation using partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Table 7 gives the number of cars (in millions) in use in the U.S. for certain years.

[image]

a) Use the method of least squares to obtain the straight line that best fits this data. (Hint: First convert *Years* to *Years after 1990*). What does he mean by the hint? I really don't understand. My idea is to rewrite it in terms of x and y then get the corresponding sums for $x_i$, $y_i$, $x_iy_i$, and $x_2$ then use the formula to find the equation of the line. But then I don't know how to rewrite it as I'm thinking if I should ever scale the values for years or leave it like that? Example, I'll make 1990 be $x=1$ then 1991 be $x=2$ and so on..

Comment: It is just to handle smaller numbers : so $1990$ becomes $0$, $1995$ becomes $5$ and so on. So the model will be $$\text{cars}=a+b \times (\text{year-1990})$$ Computing the required sums will be much simpler (if you do it by hand)

Comment: I was confused also if I should start by 1 or 0.  I was thinking if I start from 0 it'd be like 0 years so no production at all.

Comment: It does not matter at all. In fact, you define a new variable which is $z=\text{year}-\text{something}$ to make life easier. Starting at $0$ will make calculations shorter.

Comment: Okay thanks! :) Got it now.